# AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes=false doesn't work when controller validation error returns view

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC5, I have a model with an int value that is not nullable and should not be nullable, however I do not want the model binder to automatically require that field (the view is bound to a List<> and any one item in the List may be left empty and therefore not saved to db) so I am setting the following in Application_Start():

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

This works fine when my view is initially displayed, but when the user clicks Save, all validation passes, the Controller Action then does additional cross-record validation (total across records must equal 100 for instance).  If that validation fails, I then set a custom error and return the view:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Total Allocation must equal 100%.");
return View("Shipment", shipment);
```

Once that total amount is corrected, the user again clicks Save, and now <strike>the implicit Required validation starts occurring on the client-side and never sends the HttpPost back to the Controller</strike> correction: the implicit validation occurs on the server side, not client side.  That's the same implicit validation I turned off in Application_Start (I checked in debug mode and it's still false when the View returns with the error).

Is this a bug with AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes or am I doing something wrong?

TIA
-VG

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around, which I wouldn't call a "resolution" but at least it is a work-around in case someone else finds this helpful.  At first I thought the implicit validation was happening client-side, but no, it does make it into the Controller but ModelState.IsValid is now false.  This is important because my work-around relies on control being sent to the controller.  Here is what I did:

```
//Remove implicit validations
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,ModelState> stateItem in ModelState)
{
    if (stateItem.Key.Contains("AllocationAmount"))
    {
        if (stateItem.Value.Errors.Count > 0 && stateItem.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage.Contains("required"))
        {
            stateItem.Value.Errors.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}

//Check Validation
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return PartialView("pvShipment", shipment);
}
```

By checking for that specific column having a "required" error message and removing it *before* checking ModelState.IsValid, the IsValid will now return true (as long as no other errors exist of course), and is able to continue on with the save logic.  I hope this makes sense.

-VG